# Images and text are not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am having problem fixing and understanding what am I doing wrong with my code as it's not what I was trying to achieve. I would like to make a simple website responsive but whenever I tried to resize the page the image and words are moving to the left and gone off the page. Here is what is it's looking like at the moment [my work example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0N5G.png) and here is the code that I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p><b>The idea that you could outlive your money is a very real, and very worrying, prospect.</b></p>
        <p>That’s why it’s crucial you make the right decisions now.  Remember, every day you put this off is a day where the value of your nest egg is sliding <u>backwards</u>.</p>

        <div>
            <img class="photo" src="img/picture1.png" alt="Photograph"><span>Look, I know the picture can be confusing. I hope to simplify things for you and bring a bit of clarity and common sense to <i>retirement planning</i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text"><b>Me on stage in Sydney banging the drum for change</b></div>

        <p>I put the exact same case I've made to you today to 250 sophisticated investors at a conference in Sydney in March this year. Here is a picture of me on stage telling the room about ‘cash-out companies’ (right)</p>
        <p>I explained it all to them in the same way I’ve set everything out for you in this letter.</p>
        <p>At the end I asked the room how many would be interested in paying for the results of my <a href="https://www.portphillippublishing.com.au/">research</a>.</p>
        <p><b><u>Nearly everyone raised their hand</u>.</b></p>
        <p>I promise you I'll work hard for you. You don't have to be an experienced investor to know that a lot is at stake in the next few years.</p>
        <p>Remember: to make money for life you need to:</p>
        <ol type="1">
        <li>Swim with the current, not against it.</li>
        <li>Invest in thoroughly research companies.</li>
        <li>Buy my newsletter</li>
        </ol>
        <p><b><u>Categories</u></b></p>
        <ul>
        <li>Health</li>
        <li>Liberty</li>
        <li>Lifestyle</li>
            <li>Market News</li>
            <li>Opportunity</li>
        </ul>
<div class="note">
    <img src="img/capture.png" alt="quote">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 3em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol > li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}

div{
  float right;
}

.photo{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  /* width: 200px; */
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #80808052;
}

.text{
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.note{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

body{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Open Sans,sans-serif;
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand what I did wrong and point me to the right direction? I have also posted the final example of what it should looks like [final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmj4h.png). Thanks

Comment: show us what it's looking right now? And try using `%` to make it responsive

Comment: You can use media queries to make it responsive: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I have just uploaded what my example is looking like at the moment Dhavel Jardosh and I have never come across using % to making it responsive before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the `margin` that you are applying.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/x10jLucc/1/) is a fiddle of your structure which might help you solve this issue. The images might not load here due to security issues, but you can copy back the `HTML` and `CSS` to your workspace.

Comment: It's working fine when I resize the page but it's not what my final example looks like as it should be in that form and then when you resize the page it should follow with it. Thanks for helping.